# Having trouble with some basic KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm just beginning to wet my feet with KnockoutJS.  So far, I have the following:

HTML:

```
<b>Selected:</b> <span data-bind="text: selectedName" ></span>
<div data-bind="foreach: matches">
    <div data-bind="click: $root.SelectMatch" >
        <strong data-bind="text: Name" ></strong>
        <span data-bind="text: Age"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Citizenship"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.matches = ko.observableArray([
      { Name: 'Rodd Chin', Age: '42', Citizenship: 'American' },
      { Name: 'Ben Challinor', Age: '30', Citizenship: 'Russian'},
      { Name: 'Andrew Harris', Age: '35', Citizenship: 'Canadian' }
      ]);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.selectedName = ko.observable("[Empty]");
    self.SelectMatch = function (match) {
        self.selectedItem = match;
        self.selectedName = match.Name;
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
```

This all seems to work **except** for the selectedName binding of the first span tag.  For some reason that never gets updated.  I've tried adding a `ko.computed()` property to the vm that returns `self.selectedItem.Name` and binding to that but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, to set the value of an observable you shouldn't *assign* the value like this

```
self.myObservable = newValue;
```

You must *set* it like this:

```
self.myObservable(newValue);
```

This has to do with an observable being its own object and it has to maintain its subscriptions and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I also changed the binding of the span tag like so `text: selectedItem().Name`